# Organizing blogdown/Hugo structure properly for automatic update of content

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

A detailed question about organizing content for blogdown/Hugo properly.

Built two websites with blogdown/Hugo, deployed via Netlify. One is simple and is easy to update, the second starts to become a mess because of my failure to organize content properly.

Basically, as I understand, we have two main folders **/content** and **/public**.

I am developing everything in **/content**.

The current structure of **/content** looks like this.

[image]

Any folder in **/content** like **/content/team** or **/content/post** has the same structure:

- rmd files
- html files
- **/img** folder, where I store images

Example:

[image]

The problem starts at **/public** folder, it became a mess.

In my more simple web-site everything updates automatically as soon as I save my work and do `blogdown::serve_site()`. Here it is not.

For example, the same **/team** folder became a mess and looks like this.
[image]

Here I have .html index file, some other folders, which I did not create. I created **public/team/images** though, trying to understand where to locate the file.

The main problem that in this folder **/public/team** there is another folder **/public/team/team** (not sure why), where my index file is updated, when I update the code. As a result, instead of automatic update of the whole web-site content, I am forced to move .html index file from **/public/team/team** to **/public/team** manually, which sucks. Basically it forces me to have a separate index .html index file for each web-site tab, otherwise, the website has different views, when I switch tabs.

I obviously googled how to fixed this, but I found these Hugo content guideline tips not very intuitive for my level of expertise of working with blogdown/Hugo.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you remove the `public` folder and rebuild the whole side?

Comment: No idea, will try, thanks for a suggestion

Comment: `/public` folder is the output of the compiled website files, you should not edit anything under that folder.